# excel: testing conditions with if

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check different conditions using VBA for filling my columns and rows.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
For i = 1 To Lastrow
    For j = 1 To 11
        If (IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12"))) And (IsEmpty(ws1.Range("D12"))) = True Then
            ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
        ElseIf (IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12")) And (ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4))) = True Then
            ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
        ElseIf (IsEmpty(ws1.Range("D12")) And (ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4))) = True Then
            ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
        ElseIf (ws1.Cells(12, 3) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7) And ws1.Cells(12, 3) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8)) Or (ws1.Cells(12, 4) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7) And ws1.Cells(12, 4) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8)) Or ((ws1.Cells(12, 3) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7)) And (ws1.Cells(12, 4) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8))) Then
            ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

As you can see, I test a lot of conditions.

The problem is with the statements where cells C12 OR D12 are empty.
If D12 is empty the code should give me all dates that stated from date C12.

For example, I want everything that starts from 15/05/2017:

[image]

And that's the result I got:

[image]

As you can see, it's not correct.
I tested everything separately and it works, but when I get everything togheter it gets a few mistakes.

In addition, I'm really in doubt if my `If/ElseIf` statements are testing all conditions in order or if I wrote in a proper way.
Is there another way to run it in the order I want?

Comment: You don't need `= True` condition in `If` blocks. You can simply write `If <condition>`. And are your date columns actually in date format? If not, then your comparison will fail.

Comment: @Taosique but for `IsEmpty` still be necessary, doesn't it? Yes, they are... Everything is in date format, I checked.

Comment: Yes, if your business logic needs it so.

Comment: @Taosique I corrected that but it didn't affect anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't validated your IFs but a *Select* statement would be much cleaner:

```
For i = 1 To lastrow
    For j = 1 To 11
        Select Case True
            Case IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12")) And IsEmpty(ws1.Range("D12")):
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value

            Case IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12")) And ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4):
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value

            Case IsEmpty(ws1.Range("D12")) And ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4):
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value

            Case (ws1.Cells(12, 3) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7) And ws1.Cells(12, 3) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8)) Or _
                 (ws1.Cells(12, 4) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7) And ws1.Cells(12, 4) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8)) Or _
                 (ws1.Cells(12, 3) >= ws1.Cells(i, 7) And (ws1.Cells(12, 4) <= ws1.Cells(i, 8))):
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value

            Case Else:
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = "No match"
        End Select
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: I made a few modifications, but it helped me a lot... I didn't know how to use `Select Case` very well but now it's working. I just changed this `Case IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12")) And ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4):
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value` for `Case IsEmpty(ws1.Range("C12")):
                If ws1.Cells(i, 8) <= ws1.Cells(12, 4) Then
                ws2.Cells(i, j) = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
                End If`

Comment: The Select statement is much faster than IF. Just remember to use a default `Case Else` otherwise if no match you get an error.